# How to make an Instagram or Snapchat alike web page (Image Sharing)?

Tags: web, web-applications, instagram

I have to do a snapchat or instragram alike aplication, but i dont know how picture sharing work or any of the technology that those apps use (Instragram), i would like to know how i can make a file sharing app like one of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a file sharing app with almost any tech stack. If you're going to have millions of users you should carefuly select the languages and technologies you use, but you're fine for now using whatever you like the most

Anyway, here's a post from 2011 about what Instagram used to use: https://engineering.instagram.com/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances-dozens-of-technologies-adf2e22da2ad#.ikhi5ynvi

Comment: That link was very helpful. Thanks